# SQL Server Integration Services will not install

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I installed Visual Studio and now trying to add SQL Server Integration Services but it gives me this error that installation of Visual Studio is not completed. Microsoft SQL server management studio is also installed.

[image]

I tried to restart and turn off my PC but still get the same error. Does anyone knows what to do to fix this?

Comment: Check the installation logs in `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log`.